# Android Time-out Listener

Tags: java, android, timeout, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

how can i make my application in android feels that there are no events , i need the application (on any activity) to show a pop-up to the user asking "are you still there or shall i shut down !!! "

i have many activities and massive number of listeners, so making this per each

```
onTouchListener()
```

is exhausting

isn't there any other way than overriding the

```
onTouch()
```

for every activity and setting it in every

```
setOnTouchListener()
```

for every view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a base activity for you app and override [onUserInteraction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction%28%29) method.  Also take a look at [onUserLeaveHint()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint%28%29)

Comment: :D didnt know about those 2 methods, great, i'll try them asap and will reply with updates, thanks in advance